# Cauchy problem with absolute value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value, initial-value-problems, cauchy-problem

How can I solve the following Cauchy problem?

$x''(t)=\left|x\right|+t$

where

$x(0)=0$ and $x'(0)=0$?

Comment: Domain of solution? As $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @IshanDeo Non-differentiability of $|x|$ with respect to $x$ is not a problem. The Existence and Uniqueness Theorem still applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve $x'' = x + t$ with those initial conditions to get $x = \sinh(t)-t$: note that $x \ge 0$ for $t \ge 0$.  Solve $x'' = -x + t$ with the same initial conditions to get $x = t - \sin(t)$: note $x \le 0$ for $t \le 0$.
So the solution is
$$ x(t) = \cases{\sinh(t)-t & for $t \ge 0$\cr t - \sin(t) & for $t \le 0$}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how do I know that x<0 for t<0?...its obvious for t>0 that x>0 because the right side of the differential equation will be positive, so the x' is going to increase for every t>0 therefore x>0...but I dont understand the other side of t=0... is it because for t<0 the x" will be smaller than 0 thx to the initial x(0)=0 value? ...ok, but its just the environment of t=0, isnt it? another question: what happens if I change the initial x'(0)=0 to x'(0)=1!?

Comment: The solution for $x'' = x + t$ is also a solution for $x'' = |x| + t$ when $x \ge 0$, and that happens to be true here when $t \ge 0$.  The solution for $x'' = -x+t$ is also a solution for $x'' = |x| + t$ when $x \le 0$, and that happens to be true here when $t \le 0$.

Comment: What do you think happens for initial condition $x'(0)=1$?